# Can you solve this password mystery? Someone has kidnapped Mr. Fox

Tags: number-sequence

In continuation to the previous puzzle: [Puzzle1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20576/can-you-solve-this-bruce-wayne-logic-puzzle). 
This time, someone has kidnapped Mr. Fox. And all they want from Batman is the thing in the secret case (box).
But Batman doesn't know the complete password required to open the box. 
He knows that:

> - The password has a seven number key.
> - 1st five numbers are : 14, 82, 56, 130, 62.

That’s it! A bunch of random numbers, right?
Batman has nothing to go on with. 
But luckily for Mr. Fox, he once told Alfred that all his passwords have a pattern.

Help Batman save Mr. Fox. All you have to do is find the last two numbers of the key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 14->41->82, 82->28->56. 
>  Take the first two digits of a number, flip them and multiply the resulting number by 2.

Comment: Yes, correct. The logic is right.
I'm waiting for more answers, will surely mark your answer as the correct one ^_^

Answer (score 4):

From a game-theory point of view, Batman should adopt a policy of "no negotiation with hostage-takers", because if it becomes known to villains that they can get what they want through taking Batman's friends and family hostage, they'll keep on doing it.

> The logic of the no-negotiation policy is that terrorists will not take hostages if there is nothing to gain from the undertaking, i.e. a government will not concede to their demands.

http://advat.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/terrorism-game-theory.html?m=1

Compare a number of similar incidents with superhero spouses and significant others - Mary Jane, Lois Lane, etc etc.

Batman should contact Commissioner Gordon - an [armed assault by special forces, after a period of surveillance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_Embassy_siege), is in the long run a more coherent strategy than simply giving in to the hostage-taker's demands.

Comment: That's what we all call "The Goddamn Batman..." (y)